# MSDeploy error: library not found DbSqlPackage

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

Heads up: I'm a total MSDeploy noob. In fact, this is my first attempt at creating a msbuild script and I'm only recently started looking into msdeploy.

Now that that's out of the way, I'm writing a build script to compile and package my ASP.Net webforms application. The script can compile the solution, however, I'm getting the following error when attempting to package:

**Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The library 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.DbSqlPackage, Version=10.3.0.0, ...' could not be loaded.**

I've searched the web but I can't seem to find any instances of this issue (specific to the missing DbSqlPackage.dll). I assume this has something to do with the ability to package and deploy databases referenced in the solution.

I am using MSDeploy V3 and MSBuild v4.0.30319. The Package target of the .build file is as follows:

```
<Target Name="Package" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageDir>%(PackageFile.RootDir)%(PackageFile.Directory)</PackageDir>
  <Source>%(Website.FullPath)</Source>
  <Destination>%(PackageFile.FullPath)</Destination>
</PropertyGroup>
<MakeDir Directories="$(PackageDir)" />
<Exec Command='"@(MsDeploy)" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="$(Source)" -dest:package="$(Destination)"' />
```

I am not trying to include any databases and I would be happy if there is a switch that I can set to bypass the error all together. However, if anyone knows how to FIX and not just avoid the issue, that would be preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Vinney

Comment: I should add that when I run the "Build Deployment Package" function from VS 2010, this error does not occur. From what I can tell, I'm running my script is running the same msbuild/msdeploy versions.

Comment: Can you email me more details? We may have a bug here, sayedha (at)[microsoft]dotCOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to repair the installation of MS Web Deploy but no dice. Except, my filter terms "web deploy" turned up another item in my installed programs: "Web Deploy dbSqlPackage Provider" (or something along those lines... it's late). The build/package completes after removing this program.

It only took me half a day to find this solution... oh well!